# list of all valid parameters and criteria that can be used in RMA queries

Tags: allen-sdk

I would like to get specific neuron models and even though I believe I understand the RMA query system, I can not find a list of the valid keywords/arguments/criteria/parameters that would correspond to what I am looking for.
For example 'homo sapiens' as donor species is valid, and makes sense.
But if 'm__biophys_perisomatic' returns all cells with perisomatic biophysical models, what about 'all active' ones (just an example, I would be interested in many other categories)?

I assume it is obvious but I will not stumble upon it until I have posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question.  You can see what fields and associations are available for a table using the `describe` route.  For example:

http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/NeuronalModel/describe.xml

From your question, I believe you're looking at this table:

http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/ApiCellTypesSpecimenDetail/describe.xml

You can use `m__biophys_all_active` to see if a cell in that table has an all-active model.

FYI: The `ApiCellTypesSpecimenDetail` table is a denormalized table, which means it combines a complex set of relationships among tables into a single flat table.

You could similarly use the following, more generic query to find the all-active models.

[http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?criteria=model::NeuronalModel,rma::criteria,neuronal_model_template[name$eq'Biophysical - all active']&num_rows=150](http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?criteria=model::NeuronalModel,rma::criteria,neuronal_model_template[name$eq'Biophysical%20-%20all%20active']&num_rows=150)